# How to make image smaller when background-size is cover in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make website and trying to put an image in a horizontal div but when I use background-size to cover it zooms in a bit too much, so what can I do to zoom out a image when background-size is set to cover.

Comment: kindly provide us with code to work with, also have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: By 'horizontal div' do you ean one which is wide compared to height? And how does that compare to the aspect ratio of your image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the image as a background to a before pseudo element on the actual div and alter the size of that pseudo element so it never goes above the px values that you want to be the limit of the 'stretch' on your background image.

Typically these max width and height values would be the 'natural' dimensions of your image - i.e. set by the resolution with which your image has been saved.

Here's an example snippet using an image 1024px x 768px dimensions - if  you see it on a small device it'll cover the div, if on a larger one it will just center it but not allow it to be shown at too large a size (and so go 'fuzzy').

```css
div {
/* The 'horizontal' div */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20vw;
  position: relative;
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* set the maximum dimensions you are prepared for the img to be shown at */
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 1000px;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/1024/768);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;  
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```